# Python : read and compare two lists of items at the same time

Tags: python, list, algorithm, loops, tuples

I am trying to read two lists: say first list is `secret = [5, 5, 6, 0, 3]` and second list is `proposition =[5, 6, 4, 5, 5]`, each item represent a color.

My problem is the mastermind problem : given a secret list, and a proposition, i need:
For a given color, let's say 5, i need to say how many in my proposition are correctly positioned according to the secret list.
And returning a tuple given the correctly positioned '5' and the not correctly positionned '5'.

In my `proposition [5, 6, 4, 5, 5]`, the first '5' is correctly positionned according to the secret.
So the answer for the correctly positionned '5' is 1.
For the answer to evaluate the incorrectly positionned '5' in my proposition `[5, 6, 4, 5, 5]`, according to the secret `[5, 5, 6, 0, 3]`, i need to count the occurences of '5' in each list and take the minimum and remove the number of correctly positionned '5' (1 here), in secret i have 2 and in the proposition i have 3. I will be : `min(2,3)-1 = 1`.
So i need to return the `tuple (1,1)` : means 1 correctly positionned, and 1 incorrectly positionned.

To count i wrote this (i know that a count function exists for that but i am not allowed to use it):

```
def countColour (c : int, l : List[int]) -> int:
"""return # occurences of the color c inside the list l
"""
nb : int = 0
for i in range(0, len(l)):
    if (l[i] == c):
        nb = nb + 1
return nb
```

Now i am going to try to return the tuple, i wrote this code and it's seems to do the job but:

```
def eval_color(secret : List[int], prop : List[int], coul : int) -> Tuple[int,int]:
    """Return the couple (right positionned, wrong positionned) for the color c.
    """
    i : int = 0 #
    j : int = 0 #
    pbp : int = 0 # right positionned
    pmp : int = 0 # wrong positionned
    nbc_s : int = 0 # nb occurencies of color in secret
    nbc_p : int = 0 # nb occurencies of color in proposition

    c : int = coul # my color as a parameter of the function
    s : List[int] = secret
    p : List[int] = prop

    nbc_s = countColour(c,s) 
    nbc_p = countColour(c,p)

    while (i <= len(s)-1) and (j <= len(p)-1):
        if (p[j] == s[i] == c):
            pbp = pbp + 1
        i += 1
        j += 1
    return (pbp, min(nbc_s,nbc_p) - pbp)
```

Everything seems to work fine with a test like this one:

```
assert eval_color([5, 5, 6, 0, 3], [5, 6, 4, 5, 5], 5) == (1, 1)
```

Means one '5' is correctly positionned, and one '5' is incorrectly positionned.

What if i consider not just one particular color, but want to use this function to loop for each color (not just '5') of the secret list, and say how many are right positionned and incorrectly positionned in my proposition.

I tried this :

```
def evaluation(secret : List[int], prop : List[int]) -> Tuple[int,int]:
"""return the couple (total right, total wrong)
"""
pmp_tot : int = 0 # total right
pbp_tot : int = 0 # total wrong

s : List[int] = secret
p : List[int] = prop

Lt : List[Tuple(int,int)] = [] 

e : int 

for e in s:
    Lt.append(evaluation_couleur(s,p,e))

for(pbp,pmp) in Lt:
    pmp_tot = pmp_tot + pmp
    pbp_tot = pbp_tot + pbp
return (pbp_tot, pmp_tot)
```

If i tried to test with this :

```
assert evaluation([5, 5, 6, 0, 3], [5, 6, 4, 5, 5]) == (1, 2)
```

I does not work because something got wrong inside the function eval_color, and particulary inside the while loop:

```
while (i <= len(s)-1) and (j <= len(p)-1):
        if (p[j] == s[i] == c):
            pbp = pbp + 1
        i += 1
        j += 1
    return (pbp, min(nbc_s,nbc_p) - pbp)
```

I think it is not a question of programming language, it's a question of algorithm. I need to understand how to think correctly.

Thank you for your help.
PS : Remember i can not use any of the powerful weapons of Python to solve my problem.

Comment: `p[j] == s[i] == c` now you compare a Boolean to a number, `(p[j] == s[i]) == c`

Comment: I don't understand your first example, there are clearly two correctly positioned fives, right? unless I'm missing something.

Comment: You're right, in that case. I made a typo, i corrected it. secret is [5,5,6,0,3]

Comment: To @rioV8 : I compare the j-th element of p, that is p[j] with the i-th element of s, that is s[i]. If they are both equal to c, then do pbp = pbp +1. I do not catch what you mean "by you compare a Boolean to a number"

Comment: `p[j] == s[i]` is a Boolean (True/False), read up on operator precedence, place `()` in your expression to see the operator precedence, like I did

Comment: To rioV8 what should i write to compare two element of two lists with a partiular value?

Answer (score 0):

I've edited the code based on your input but not sure if it breaks your rules.

```
secret = [5, 5, 6, 0, 5]
proposition = [5, 6, 4, 5, 5]

def program(secret: list[...], proposition: list[...]):
    matches = {}
    counter = 0

    while counter != len(proposition):
        check_value = proposition[counter]

        if proposition[counter] == secret[counter]:
            if check_value not in matches.keys():
                matches[check_value] = [1, 0]

            else:
                matches[check_value][0] += 1

        else:
            if check_value not in matches.keys():
                matches[check_value] = [0, 1]

            else:
                matches[check_value][1] += 1

        counter += 1

    return matches


find_all = program(secret, proposition)

print(find_all)
```

Comment: Thank you The problem comes from the Mastermind game. And i am not allowed to use any tools like zip, group, index. I have the right to use only List and Tuple with loops.

Comment: Thank you, it does the job for one value '5'. How to deal with it if your request is not a single value as '5' but a list, let say the secret list. It means that your loop needs to work as many times as the list secret has values.

Comment: what do you mean? A secret list of lists? Or do you mean a different request number? If it's the latter, all you need to do is call the program within a loop with each call changing the request value.

Comment: Sorry for my delayed answer : I mean loop over a list of values, instead of a single value. Instead of "find_fives = program(5, secret, proposition) " would be "find_all = program(list_of_values, secret, proposition)"